# Downloading Java JRE

Tags: java, jre

Today, I have been trying to install Java [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment). I have meet some problems. I downloaded the file from Java's website. The file name is `jre-7u25-linux-i586.tar.gz`. I then extracted the file and have it in my downloads.

I know would like to complete the download, but how do complete this last step?

Answer (score 2):

A JRE is already available in the Ubuntu repositories: OpenJDK. It is not the official Oracle JRE, but it works fine.

To install it, just execute in the console:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

For Java support in the browser, execute:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

Note: you could use the Ubuntu Software Center to search and install those packages.

---

OpenJDK works fine, but if you want the official Oracle JRE, replace the first command by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```